# How can I color the specific clicked button using the button index?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Manager : EditorWindow
{
    private static bool red;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Manager")]
    static void Managers()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<Manager>();
        Init();
    }

    private static void Init()
    {
        red = true;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUIContent c = new GUIContent();

        var style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);

        if (red)
        {
            style.normal.textColor = Color.red;
        }
        else
        {
            style.normal.textColor = Color.green;
        }
        style.fontSize = 18;

        string[] Paths = new string[2];
        string[0] = "testing1";
        string[1] = "testing2";

        for (int i = 0; i < Paths.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Paths[i].Contains("test")) // or .js if you want
            {
                var x = assetPaths[i].LastIndexOf("/");
                var t = assetPaths[i].Substring(x + 1);

                GUILayout.Button(t, style, GUILayout.Width(1000), GUILayout.Height(50));
                if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint && GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect().Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
                {
                    OnMouseOver(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseOver(int buttinIndex)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("OnMouseOver {0}", buttinIndex);
        red = !red;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I move the mouse cursor over one of the buttons it's coloring all the buttons in green then back to red.

I want that when I click on specific button or move the mouse cursor over a specific button color only this button in green and leave the button in green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should record the style for each button use List or something else.

At current you code lead all button use one same style so they change together.

I supply a tip. I hope this can help you.

```
private void OnMouseOver(int buttinIndex)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogFormat("OnMouseOver {0}", buttinIndex);
    //red = !red; 
    //try to record style or color flag for each button use index.
}
```

and when you draw button

```
GUILayout.Button(t, GetStyleFromList(i), GUILayout.Width(1000), GUILayout.Height(50));
```

Comment: This is working great. I'm facing also two more sub problems. Should I open a new question ? First how can I add a scroll bar to see all the items in the window from top to bottom ? Second now when I change the window size top and bottom it's coloring the buttons text to green automatic. Like when changing the window size with the mouse it's coloring the buttons text to green not sure why, it's like it's doing repaint.

Comment: @BenBenShmil I suggest you make a new question about sub question1.Because I'm not sure how to help you.For sub question2 .When you changing the window size It still doing repaint. So if you get size changed event do not call on mouse over.I hope this can help you.